# Render Markdown tables correctly

Tags: tables, markdown, rendering

I am trying to render Markdown tables using the `markdown` package. The tables do get rendered properly in Pandoc, but not with LaTeX.
Here is my .tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=1.25in, bottom=1.25in, left=1in, right=3in]{geometry}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Today}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{202F}{\,}
\usepackage{markdown}

\begin{document}
\markdownInput{test.md}
\end{document}
```

And my .md:

```markdown
## Some title

A few words before the table.

| Product                                   | Price   |
| :---------------------------------------- | :------ |
| Good                                      | 14 €/kg |
| Better                                    | 19 €/kg |
| Best                                      | 32 €/kg |
```

Instead of rendering the table, LaTeX creates a pdf where the whole table and format is just words inline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the package option `pipeTables=true`, this setting is false by default.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=1.25in, bottom=1.25in, left=1in, right=3in]{geometry}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Today}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{202F}{\,}
\usepackage[pipeTables=true]{markdown}

\begin{document}
\markdownInput{tableinput.md}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks pretty terrible, actually (through no fault of your own). I suppose we should provide a saner default renderer prototype for tables without captions.